# Why is Snowflake query result via curl of DATE type returned as days from 1970-01-01?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The query is via curl call in php to `https://<account>.snowflakecomputing.com/queries/<token>/result`

The 'rowtype' of the field is

```
{
    "name": "SNAPSHOT_DATE",
    "database": <database>,
    "schema": <schema>,
    "table": "DAILY_USER_SNAPSHOT",
    "byteLength": null,
    "type": "date",
    "scale": null,
    "precision": null,
    "nullable": true,
    "collation": null,
    "length": null
}
```

The 'rowset' of the field is `"18350"`, which is the number of days since 1970-01-01 (Unix epoch date).

In the web UI Worksheet, the field is return as expected in the DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT of YYYY-MM-DD  (verified with `SHOW PARAMETERS in account;`) like this:

```
2020-03-29
```

Why isn't the 'rowset' of the field via the curl call returned as `"2020-03-29"` instead of as `"18350"`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it is probably just the standard format that Snowflake returns date/time datatypes in via API calls. It's up to the client application to determine how it gets rendered on screen. The WebUI is one of these clients using the API and it (probably) uses the session parameters [for output formats shown here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#output-formats) to determine how to display it to the users.

Why are you using curl / rest API to get this data and not one of the drivers provided by Snowflake?

Comment: I think the curl calls constitute ODBC calls, like `/queries/v1/query-request` as opposed to the API documented at https://api.snowflake.ai/

But I can't find anything specifically about DATE types being returned as days-since-Epoch. I guess I'll just have to go forward with one of the workaround alternatives I came up with.



To answer your last question, it was already done before I started working on it. I'll give you an upvote or whatever when I have the reputation or whatever.